# How can I do a hierarchical validation in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm writing a Django app, where users can upload CSV files. Therefore I've created an upload model with three validators:

- One that checks the file extension (`FileExtensionValidator`),
- one for the MIME type validation (`ValidateFileType`),
- and a third one for parsing the CSV file and checking for data types, right number of columns and so on (`ValidateCsv`).

It'd be reasonable to check the upload only with the next validator if the preceding validation didn't raise a `ValidationError`.

For instance, the user could upload a .py file. This would raise an error in all three validators, but I want to avoid, that Django checks the MIME type or even tries to treat and parse a .py file as a CSV file, although the file extension wasn't correct right from the beginning.

So here is my model for the user's upload:

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from .utils import unique_file_path
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
from .validators import ValidateFileType, ValidateCsv

class Upload(models.Model):
    date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=unique_file_path, validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['csv']), ValidateFileType, ValidateCsv], max_length=255)
```

With this `validators` list all three validations are always performed and I can see all the error messages in `upload_form.errors`. For example:

> File extension 'py' is not allowed. Allowed extensions are: 'csv'.
>   File type text/x-python not supported.
>   Some data is invalid. Please check your CSV file.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Upload

class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
```

**view.py**

```py
from .forms import UploadForm

def someView(request):
    upload_form = UploadForm()
    ...
    context = {'upload_form': upload_form}
    return render(request, 'someTemplate.html', context)
```

Do you have an idea, what's the best approach to make such a hierarchical chain of validators? Of course I could write some big all-in-one validator function, but since I use a Django core validator, I dont't want to rewrite this one, but combine existing django validators with my own ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to rewrite the django core validator.

In your validators file:

```
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator

def ValidateFileType(value):
   ....your code....

def ValidateCsv(value):
   ....your code....

def csv_validator(value):
    '''Your all in one function'''
    extension = FileExtensionValidator(['csv'])
    extension(value) #FileExtensionValidator is a callable class. See docs for that.
    ValidateFileType(value)
    ValidateCsv(value)
```

Don't know if that's the best way, but it should do the trick.